# How to find the longest same character in a string?

Tags: c, string

Input: `aabbbccbc` 
Output: `3`

Here the longest repeated same character is `b` [aa(bbb)ccbc], because there is a sequence of 3 `b`s together.

I have to input one string, I have to use merge sort and recursion to sort the string and then have to find the longest same character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int lsc(char *a, int p, int r);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int l = strlen(argv[1]);

    printf("%d \n", lsc(argv[1], 0, l - 1));
    return 0;
}
```

This is the `main` function of that code. I have to create `int lsc(char *a, int p, int r)` function to check the input.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: After dividing the string till it's single character, I am thinking about comparing the characters with each other by their ASCII value. If I find same ASCII value then I'll make a positive counter. But I don't know if that's the correct way to solve it.

Comment: Why do you "have" to use merge sort? This seems like an easy problem where you generate an array of counts indexed by character:   |for i = 0 to n-1 | count[array[i]]++ |, followed by a single scan of counts[] to find the largest count.

Comment: Can you please explain how to even use merge sort for this problem?  Since the order matters for the count I don't see how sorting can be helpful at all?

Comment: @kim: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 2):

Sorting the string does not help for this problem, in fact the string should not be changed at all since doing that could produce a different result: `aabbbccbc` would be come `aabbbbccc` with a result of 4.

The solution is rather straightforward. Follow these steps:

- if the string is empty, the longest sequence is `0`.
- otherwise start with a sequence of 1 repetition of the first character: `max = count = 1`.
- if the next character is identical, increase le repeat count (`count++`), if the repeat count exceeds the current maximum, increase that (`max++`).
- otherwise, reset the repeat count to 1 (`count = 1`)
- skip to the next character
- when you reach the end of the string, return `max`.

Comment: It's stronger than "no need to sort the string"; it's more like "the string must not be sorted" (because given the example `aabbbccbc`, if the string was sorted, the answer would be `4`, not `3`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: indeed I should have been more direct. Answer amended.